# Displaying today`s date using DisplayFormat

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using

```
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yy}")]
```

but the problem i`m having is it`s always displaying 01-Jan-01 if the date value is null.

I am also using jquery for the display as follows:

```
 $("#DateFrom").datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
          altField: 'dd-M-yy',
          altFormat: 'd/m/y',
          minDate: new Date(2010, 1 - 1, 1),
          maxDate: '+12m +1w'
      });
```

I want to dipsly today`s date by default if the date value is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set it in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    viewModel.DateFrom = FetchDateFromSomewhere() ?? DateTime.Now;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

or in the getter of your view model:

```
private DateTime? _dateFrom;
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yy}")]
public DateTime? DateFrom
{
    get 
    {  
        return _dateFrom ?? DateTime.Now;
    }
    set
    {
        _dateFrom = value;
    }
}
```